# Updating relationships through Rails with Datamapper ORM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datamapper

I'm using Rails 3 and Datamapper together and all is fine except when I'm setting many to many relationships.

If I'm trying to **update** a user through the Rails controller I run:

```
@user.update(params[:user])
```

Within params is a role_ids collection. However, when I pass this through I get the following message:

```
The attribute 'role_ids' is not accessible in User
```

The relationship on the user side of the model looks like:

```
has n, :roles, :through => Resource
```

I can't see what the problem is here - can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This means you don't have "role_ids" field in your User model - which is true as most probably you have "resource_id" in your User model. 
If you have a form to accept role creation/modification within a user creation/modification, you will have to declare that in User like this:

```
class User
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles
  attr_accessible :role_attributes
```